# Trouble with creating table in Redshift via Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am following this tutorial: [How to Create Redshift Table from DataFrame using Python](https://dwgeek.com/create-redshift-table-from-dataframe-using-python.html/)

This is my code so far:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import config
from airtable import Airtable
import psycopg2

# Connect to Airtable
base_id = '###'
table_name = '###'
api_key = '###'

airtable = Airtable(base_id, table_name, api_key=api_key)
record_list = airtable.get_all()

print("Airtable was a sucesss")

# Create the dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame([record['fields'] for record in record_list])

print("Dataframe done")

dbname = config.dbname
host = config.host
port = config.port
user = config.user
password = config.password

conn = sa.create_engine('postgresql://' + user + ':' + password + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + dbname)

data.to_sql('test_table_python', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

It is supposed to get data via API from Airtable (this works), turn it into a dataframe (also works), then is supposed to push that dataframe to AWS Redshift and create a new table... that's where it fails.

The failure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dakota/Desktop/testing/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1284, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/Users/dakota/Desktop/testing/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName: no schema has been selected to create in

~~

  File "/Users/dakota/Desktop/testing/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) no schema has been selected to create in

[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE test_table_python (
        "Name" TEXT, 
        "Notes" BIGINT, 
        "Attachments" TEXT, 
        "Account status" TEXT
)

]
```

I see the `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) no schema has been selected to create in` but I am not entirely sure what that means. I have Googled and searched the documentation but have had no luck...

I have tried basic things like formatting and double checking credentials, but I honestly have no idea what to do now.

Comment: The table should ideally be created in the Public schema. Were the usage privileges on public schema revoked explicitly for this user?

Comment: In redshift- check the search_path for this user. if it is not there then set it.By the way - this is not the way you want to be processing data in to redshift - it will be VERY slow.

Comment: Thanks both! I will double check although I thought this user was the admin. 

@JonScott is there any other method you would recommend? Sorry to be so needy.

Comment: you need to go pandas->s3->redshift.. you could check out something like https://github.com/agawronski/pandas_redshift but i have not used it